# Search working on full search only not a partial search ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following search query

```
where("contact_type = 'supplier' and name = '#{search}'")
```

Let's say I'm searching for `John` for `John Doe` this doesn't work, however, if I search for the full name `John Doe` the search works. How do I get it so I can do a partial search while retaining the current query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to try `like` query:

```
where("contact_type = 'supplier' and name like ?", "%#{search}%")
```